# What's the word for the taste of gooseberries, unripe bananas, or betel nuts?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

In my native language, Tamil, *arusuvai* means six tastes namely *uvarppu* (salty), *inippu* (sweet), *kasappu* (bitter), *pulippu* (sour), *kaarppu* (pungent e.g. chilli) and *thuvarpu*. I am looking for a word in English for the last one. It's neither umami nor astringent.

It's the taste you experience when biting into gooseberries or betel nuts or unripe bananas.

Comment: If you can't find it in a Tamil-English dictionary, then it's unlikely a direct translation exists. Googling does suggest the most common translation is indeed *astringent*, so if that's not satisfactory to you, explaining why would help people understand what directions are likely to be more or less fruitful. English language articles on gooseberries describe them as *sour* and betel nuts as *bitter*. So it seems like in English there is no one word which captures all these flavors. It's somewhere in the range of sour/tart/bitter/astringent.

Comment: What other food items have this taste for you? Gooseberries are sour, but green bananas just taste "green" like other unripe fruit.

Comment: @Dan Gooseberries don't taste sour, it tastes thuvarpu then sweet, which in the literatures saying "Nellikai muthiyor Sol polla munnae thuvarkum pinnae innikum" meaning Gooseberry, like elder's word tastes thuvarpu early, then sweet later.

Comment: @Mambo I've never had gooseberries, or if I have, I don't remember them.  I'm just telling you how I found their taste described in English - if you search for "the taste of gooseberries" (in English) and read the articles and other write-ups, the word used is *sour*. What I think this tells you is there is no single word in English that captures the flavor *thuvarpu*. My best guess is it's somewhere on the spectrum of what English describes as sour/tart/bitter/astringent. I don't think you'll get a more precise word than that, or we'd have found it already. Or I could be wrong.

Comment: I find gooseberries a bit like lemons/limes. They have a sweetness to them, but it's also overpowered by a very tart flavour (when not cooked)

Comment: Wikipedia lists "astringent" as a taste. Because it's often associated with tannins (as in red wine) an alternative might be "tannic".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astringent_(taste)

Comment: "Astringent" definitely covers the mouth-feel aspect, and the description is exactly what I thought of when the OP mentioned bananas. Anecdotally: I personally do not attach a taste to the word astringent, so I wondered briefly what it might imply, but I find "tannic/tannin" to evoke the concept immediately.

Comment: 'astringent' is the most common response on a google search on the English letter string 'thuvarpu'.

Answer (score 6):

From what I gather "astringent" is often used for this sixth taste. That may seem inappropriate to you. In terms of taste, which can be very subjective, the word "acidic" might be an appropriate English word to convey the taste. Other English taste words might be to give quality of "brightness" or "freshness".

http://www.nithyasnalabagam.com/2013/06/six-tastes-of-food-arusuvai-unnavu.html

Comment: Isn't 'acidic' the same as 'sour'?

Comment: astringent is more of a mouthfeel than a taste.

Answer (score 5):

The science is a bit incomplete on this topic, as reflected in the language. There are four non-controversial tastes in the western nomenclature: sweet, sour, salty, and bitter, and a recent addition of umami. Umami was only proposed in early 1900s, and wasn't generally accepted in the scientific community until the 1980s or so. MSG is to umami as salt is to salty.

There is a movement now for a sixth taste, as reflected in Wikipedia:

> In Asian countries within the sphere of mainly Chinese and Indian cultural influence, pungency (piquancy or hotness) had traditionally been considered a sixth basic taste.

This may be the best translation.

You'll also find references to a seventh taste there, related to fatty foods.

The science is very immature, especially when compared to vision and audition. We're likely decades away from real consensus, and a stable vocabulary.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taste)

Comment: A very sane answer.

Answer (score 2):

There no English word to describe thuvarpu in Tamil. However "pulippu" and "Thuvarpu" are entirely different taste English use sour for both.

Answer (score 2):

In Tamil pulippu and thuvarpu are totally different tastes. In English we use *sour* for pulippu and *astringent* for thuvarpu.