# Word for the flavor found in green bananas or green persimmon

Tags: single-word-requests, food

I have been asking this questions to a few native English speakers but none have given me a satisfactory answer, and it has been bugging me for so long.

What is the English word for the flavor that found in green fruits like green bananas or green persimmon? The closest I have found is *bitter*, but if you have eaten those 2 fruits, you would know it is not bitter. In Vietnamese we say “chát”, which when put in Google Translate it came out as “acrid” but the explanation doesn’t sound right, so here I am asking this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the numb sensation in the mouth caused by some fruits called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132194/what-is-the-numb-sensation-in-the-mouth-caused-by-some-fruits-called) /// Also [**this one**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/442352/equivalent-word-for-a-particular-taste-in-english)

Answer (score 20):

**Astringent**

> Astringent is a taste that puckers the mouth, numbs the tongue, and constricts the throat. This taste is caused by astringents such as
> tannins.
>
> The astringent taste is in **unripened bananas, unripe persimmons** and
> cashew fruits.
>
> [Astringent (taste) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astringent_(taste))

Comment: I associate *astringent* with citrus-y white wines that cleanse the palate (by resetting other tastes). In contrast, green bananas leave a taste in my mouth. But good find on the Wikipedia reference.

Comment: I think that this is the most correct answer, but would like to point out that the word "astringent" is a bit on the obscure side, and I (Am Eng speaker) have heard and used the phrase "mouth puckering". It's a bit more informal, but the phrase "Those are some really mouth puckering bananas. I'd let them ripen a bit more." would be valid in my social circles.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've heard neither phrase, and I'm sure the OP's initial experience struggling to get a satisfying answer from native speakers is evidence that most people just _don't have a term_ for this.

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings - "astringent" is familiar to me and I'm no cook.  I thought of the word and only afterwards did I discover that there was a Wiki article about it.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I'm sure _some_ people are familiar with it. Great that you're one of them; congratulations!

Comment: I wouldn't call "astringent" an obscure word. It's about halfway down [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), but it's used quite regularly to describe facial cleaners such as witch hazel and Sea Breeze that are found in everyday stores.

Comment: @rajah9 Like many flavor words, there are slight differences when talking about wines. Technically though both are still astringent, because the important part is the physiological reaction (which actually _isn’t_ a taste, it’s an involuntary contraction of the mucus membranes in the mouth, just like the sensation produced by capsaicin isn’t a taste but an inflammatory reaction), and both are still caused primarily by tannins.

Comment: @shoover While not exactly obscure, usage to refer to ‘flavor’ is not exactly common outside of describing wines with a high tannin content that is a major component of their taste.

Comment: Astringent do look familiar, but now when i google it, its usage have been steadily decline, so maybe that is why most of my friends can’t think about it on top of their head. Also the wine references are true, we do use “chát” as a word to describe wine flavor.

Comment: While I have no problem with using the word astringent here, I found this description that might be colorful enough to repeat.  It was in a description for unripe philodendron fruit but could work for this arguably milder experience.  Following  Austin Hemmelgarn's lead, it is not exactly flavor we are discussing, but the body's reaction to something.

" Unripe fruits are chock full of oxalic acid, a substance that is used to bleach wood and clean rust off metal."

While lemon makes your mouth pucker, unripe bananas, persimmons and philodendrons make your body react as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest answer is [*tannic*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tannic), which comes from [tannins](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tannin):

> A yellowish or brownish bitter-tasting organic substance present in some galls, barks, and other plant tissues, consisting of derivatives of gallic acid.

(Copied from Lexico)

I believe the sensation from green bananas is produced by a similar process as tannins in red wine. For me that is a particularly unpleasant feeling that makes me grimace and pull my lips over my teeth.

It can easily be confused with bitterness but is quite different from the sourness of lemons, etc.

So, you could say

> These green bananas are very tannic.

Comment: The Lexico link gives as example a description of the taste of a wine. I don't think people who are not wine experts would use the word in everyday conversation.

Comment: @KateBunting possibly so. I did learn it while working selling wine.

Comment: While I closely associate *tannic* with red wines, strongly-brewed tea also comes to mind.

Comment: @rajah9 yes, I know what you mean! I think that's the same thing, too.

Comment: As we Vietnamese use the same word for both wine flavor and green banana, i would say this is the right answer. Now i would have to use both words to describe this then